# Oscommerce v2.3.3.4 send email to newsletter subscribers

Tags: oscommerce

I am using `oscommerce v2.3.3.4` and any emails sent to `All Newsletter Subscribers` using `'Send Email'` option under Tools aren't being delivered. According to `oscommerce`, they are being sent - but I'm not receiving anything.

I can however send emails using the same method to all customers or individual customers, so there doesn't appear to be any issues with the `sendmail` option under the configuration.

I have checked the database and newsletter subscribers are being captured in the `newsletter_subscriber` table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to check your reverse DNS settings as your mail is probably being blocked as spam.

Sending bulk mail shots from your webserver is not advisable these days. Look to using Amazon SES or an easier option is to use a newsletter managements system such as Mail Chimp

Comment: I don't think it's DNS related. If it were, I don't think it would allow any sending of emails. It specifically doesn't deliver to newsletter subscribers which I can clearly see are being captured in the database. I'm putting it down to an Oscommerce bug.

I did read up, that Mailchimp has an API for integrating Oscommerce newsletter subscribers into their mailing lists.

I'm going to mark your answer as correct for mentioning Amazon SES and Mail Chimp.